# FDR calculation using True positive, negative and False positive negative in R?

Tags: r

Assume that Object A,B,C,D are supposed to be positive value. On the other hand, the object E,F,G,H are negative that are supposed scored as negative value. I want to calculate True positive and negative & False positive negatve in order to calculate FDR in the end. How to calculate FDR for each object  in R?
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhrpd.png)

Answer (score 0):

In R FDR calculations are best accomplished with inputs as p-values using the `p.adjust` function.  Given that p-values range from 0 to 1, your description leads me to believe that your source statistic is not a p-value.  Do you know on what distribution objects A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H are on?  Do you know if you desire a one or two tailed test?

Comment: I performed baysian Analysis using the reference set, and the positive and negative objects are reference set. The Objects are supposed to be genes and the scores are Bayes Factor(BF) therefore there is no p-value to calculate FDR. I should have explained the Details earlier.  Lack of my statistics knowledge, I was following calculation from " False discovery rate is (FP/FP + TP),
precision is 1- FDR, and recall = TP/(TP + FN), where
positives and negatives are defined in the reference sets".